# How can I set a min width and a max width to a button in iOS autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a mobile dev beginner coming from the web. In css I'd do `min-width: 40%; max-width: 90%;`

How can I reproduce this in iOS interface builder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create constains saying that `button.width <= superview.Width * 0.4`
Like following picture:

[image: Like following]

Comment: Here only Min width you are setting. Does it possible to set both Min and Max for a control?

Answer (score 1):

By using NSAutoLayoutConstraints you can set any relation to any property. In your case you are looking for something like:

```
let lowerWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:contentView,
    attribute:.Width,
    relatedBy:.GreaterThanOrEqual,
    toItem:parentView,
    attribute:.Width,
    multiplier:0.4,
    constant:0);
```

So, in that case you creating constraint, which has relation Grater Or Equal than some other view, and multiplayer is 40% (0.4)

contentView in that example is your view, and parentView - any view at the same level of view hierarchy.

and in the same way you can set less than 90%:

```
let upperWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:contentView,
    attribute:.Width,
    relatedBy:.LessThanOrEqual,
    toItem:parentView,
    attribute:.Width,
    multiplier:0.9,
    constant:0);
```